# counting the backslashes in each string of an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I want to count how many times a backslash "/" is in a array of urls

and print out the value of each url

this is what i have right now in java

```
public class Main
{
public static void main (String[]args){
    int count = 0;
    String [] array = {"https://www.hello.com/app/login/","https://www.hello.com/sam/"    
 };
    for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++){


        for(int z = 0;z<array[i].length();z++){

            if(array[i].charAt(z) == '/')
             {    
           count++;

        }


        }
        System.out.println(count);



    }



}
```

}

but it prints our 5 and 9 , the number 9 represent the whole number of backlashes in the array i want the number of backslashes for the second url. not the over all number

Comment: Note about terms:  ```/``` is a slash; ```\``` is a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the count to 0 after the inner for loop is finished:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int count = 0;
        String [] array = {"https://www.hello.com/app/login/","https://www.hello.com/sam/"};
        for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++){

            for(int z = 0;z<array[i].length();z++){
                 if(array[i].charAt(z) == '/')
                 {    
                    count++;
                 }
             }
             System.out.println(count);
             count = 0; // reset the counter to 0 here
        }
    }
}
```